# How to customize only one node near coord?

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      symbolic x coords={Germany,Spain,UK},
      xtick={Germany,Spain,UK},
      xticklabels={\bfseries\textcolor{green}{Germany},Spain,UK},
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      x tick label style={rotate=45},
      ymin=0,
      enlarge x limits={abs=0.5cm},
      ymax=110,
      ytick={0,10,...,100},
      ybar=6pt,
      bar width=14pt,
      nodes near coords, 
      ylabel=\% blablabla     
    ]
    \addplot[bar shift=0pt,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (Germany,10)
        };
    \addplot[bar shift=0pt,fill=red] coordinates {
         (Spain,30)       
        };
    \addplot[bar shift=0pt,fill=yellow] coordinates {
         (UK,40)       
        };    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want the node near coord "10" to be green and in bold face, as the "Germany" coord. Is it possible?

Comment: Although it is good you provide an MWE, we prefer not to be a code-writing service (teach a man to fish and all)... Could you let us know, what have you tried that isn't working? What pages in the manual have you read that haven't worked out?

Comment: I checked the manual but did not find any example where only one node is customized, so I thought it would be appropriate to ask here. I can customize all nodes together, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `every node near coord/.style={text=green,font=\boldmath}` as in

```
\addplot[bar shift=0pt,fill=blue,every node near coord/.style={text=green,font=\boldmath}] coordinates {
        (Germany,10)
        };
```